# Issue with javascript permission denied from iframe, even when it is the same domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am having the eternal battle against same origin policy.

I have a registration process loaded dynamically to a page in an iframe. This process is on a different domain which I know is prohibited via the same origin policy.

However ! at the end of the process I direct the frame back to a page on the parent domain with a url variable and then fire a function to refresh the page.

I assumed that as the page is now on the same domain this would not be an issue and on firefox and chrome it works great, however on ie it still throws a permission denied error.

The function im running inside the iframe

```
if(gup("command") == "refresh"){                
    parent.samRefresh();                
        }
```

And in the parent frame I have

```
function samRefresh(){
    location.reload(true);

}
```

Does any one have any ideas? I know that there are some scripts knocking around to do this however I would prefer not to use them if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In iFrame:

```
window.parent.success_msg(deferred);
```

On parent page:

```
window.success_msg = function(dfd) {
    console.log("I'm from the parent window");
};
```

Also make sure you're running localhost rather than viewing your files from your file system.